# Drive unmountable FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF issue

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, filesystem, filevault

I have the standard single drive inside my MBP. The issue is inside my external usb drive.

The HDD had 4 (visible) partitions:

- My Passport (Core Storage volume) 959 gb
- SSD (backup for my mbp) 339 gb
- A linux partition, which I have formatted called lin 140 gb.
- and i'm not sure why this Boot OS X one appeared, but it has 134 mb.
- Lasty there is disk2s5, which is filevault encrypted using Yosemite.

  It used to be called HDD though. This is the drive I really want to recover and I do not care about anything else on the hdd, but this partition.

I have read some of the other instructions, but would really appreciate if someone could guide me a little more with this. I don't want to risk messing this partition up, because it has music and media that is really vital and important to me. I would be forever grateful if someone could help.

```
/dev/disk0
    #:                       TYPE NAME                        SIZE   IDENTIFIER
    0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
    1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
    2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         120.5 GB   disk0s2
    3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
    #:                       TYPE NAME                        SIZE   IDENTIFIER
    0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *120.1 GB   disk1
                             Logical Volume on disk0s2
                             A55BEF41-A7E8-48E8-968E-78E38DEFC708
                             Unlocked Encrypted
/dev/disk2
    #:                       TYPE NAME                     SIZE      IDENTIFIER
    0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
    1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
    2:                  Apple_HFS SSD                     399.4 GB   disk2s2
    3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk2s3
    4:                  Apple_HFS Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s4
    5: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF               500.0 GB   disk2s5
    6:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s6
    7:                  Apple_HFS My Passport             959.0 GB   disk2s7
    8:                  Apple_HFS lin                     140.6 GB   disk2s9
hz:~ hn$ sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk2
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640   779980464      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   780390104     1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   781659640      262144      4  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   781921784   976562504      5  GPT part - FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF
  1758484288      262144      6  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1758746432  1873040464      7  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  3631786896      262144         
  3632049040   274652232      8  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  3906701272      262151         
  3906963423          32         Sec GPT table
  3906963455           1         Sec GPT header
```

Update after the Recovery HD was removed (by accident?):

```
/dev/disk2
  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
  0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
  1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
  2:                  Apple_HFS SSD                     399.4 GB   disk2s2
  3:                  Apple_HFS Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s3
  4: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF               500.0 GB   disk2s4
  5:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s5
  6:                  Apple_HFS My Passport             959.0 GB   disk2s6
  7:                  Apple_HFS lin                     140.6 GB   disk2s7

 sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk2
     start        size  index  contents
         0           1         PMBR
         1           1         Pri GPT header
         2          32         Pri GPT table
        34           6         
        40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
    409640   779980464      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
 780390104     1269536         
 781659640      262144      3  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
 781921784   976562504      4  GPT part - FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF
1758484288      262144      5  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
1758746432  1873040464      6  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
3631786896      262144         
3632049040   274652232      7  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
3906701272      262151         
3906963423          32         Sec GPT table
3906963455           1         Sec GPT header

hn:~ hnn$ diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk2
 Unmount of all volumes on disk2 was successful
hn:~ hnn$ sudo gpt remove -i 5 /dev/disk2
/dev/disk2s5 removed
hn:~ hnn$ diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk2
Unmount of all volumes on disk2 was successful
hn:~ hnn$ sudo gpt add -i 5 -b 781921784 -s 976562504 -t 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk2
gpt add: /dev/disk2: error: no space available on device
```

Answer (score 2):

The partition disk2s5 has the wrong partition type. It should be 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC instead of FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF!

To solve this boot to Macintosh HD (disk0s2/disk1), open Terminal and enter:

- to get an overview:

  ```
  diskutil list
  ```

  below I assume the external disk has the disk identifier disk2

  ```
  sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk2
  ```
- unmount disk2:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk2
  ```
- remove the partition entry with the index 5 (and the type FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF):

  ```
  sudo gpt remove -i 5 /dev/disk2
  ```
- re-add the same partition entry but with the proper type:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk2
  sudo gpt add -i 5 -b 781921784 -s 976562504 -t 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk2
  ```
- the external file vault volume (disk2s5) should be mounted automatically and you will be asked for the password. If not, enter `diskutil cs list` and `diskutil cs unlockVolume lvUUID` (with lvUUID: the Logical Volume UUID inside the second Logical Volume Group)

---

Update because the Recovery HD partition was removed somehow:

- Remove all partitions:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk2
  sudo gpt destroy /dev/disk2
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk2
  sudo gpt create -f /dev/disk2
  ```
- re-add all partitions one by one:

  ```
  sudo gpt add -i 1 -b 40 -s 409600 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B /dev/disk2
  sudo gpt add -i 3 -b 780390104 -s 1269536 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk2
  sudo gpt add -i 4 -b 781659640 -s 262144 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk2
  sudo gpt add -i 6 -b 1758484288 -s 262144 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk2
  sudo gpt add -i 8 -b 3631786896 -s 262144 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk2
  sudo gpt add -i 10 -b 3906701272 -s 262144 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk2
  sudo gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 779980464 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk2
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk2
  sudo gpt add -i 7 -b 1758746432 -s 1873040464 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk2
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk2
  sudo gpt add -i 9 -b 3632049040 -s 274652232 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk2
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk2
  sudo gpt add -i 5 -b 781921784 -s 976562504 -t 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk2
  ```

I have chosen a "non-sequential" adding of partitions to unmount disk2 less often!

Comment: I seem to get an error nearly at the end. I have added the progress above, but here is the ending notes.  sudo gpt add -i 5 -b 781921784 -s 976562504 -t 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk2
Password:
gpt add: /dev/disk2: error: no space available on device

Comment: @uuresearcher Hmm your first `gpt ... disk2` is different compared to your second `gpt .. disk2`. Why?

Comment: @uuresearcher You removed your partition -i 3 meanwhile! That's a recovery HD!

Comment: I see what you mean. I see that the recovery HD is no longer listed.

Comment: @uuresearcher Updated answer to reflect the missing Recovery HD

Comment: You're a scholar and a gentleman/woman! It worked. I wish I could do something back for you. If you are ever in Stockholm, I'd be happy to buy ya dinner and tour you around haha.

Comment: @uuresearcher You may accept the answer because it solved your problem ;-). I will contact you as soon as I have the pleasure to visit Stockholm...