# Partition FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF need data from that disk! help

Tags: hard-drive, partition

I wanted to upgrade my MacBook pro mid 2012 with ssd (old HDD instead of DVD drive). I removed HDD from default place and installed new SSD in that place, installed fresh system, plugged HDD instead of DVD drive and now my HDD is bricked. Also this disk was split in two partitions: 450GB (<- data which i need and would be great if i didnt lose it) and 50GB where was windows 7 installed. Unfortunately i deleted this 50GB partition with disk utility and now i can see only 450 GB partition. SSD: Yosemite, HDD: Catalina.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Is there any solution that would fix HDD so i could transfer data to other disk?

**EDIT #1**

I've followed this thread: [Drive unmountable FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/241796/drive-unmountable-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff-issue?rq=1)

[image]

Can somebody tell me what should be next step?

[image]

Comment: Please search before posting - https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=ffffffff

Comment: So your first step was to create a backup??

Comment: Unfortunately i have no backup of HDD, that's why i ask for help to recover data from it. I've seen similar threads but im afraid to do anything cause im scared i'll delete sth...

Comment: Somebody help me please